# WSO2IS AssertionConsumerServiceURL using localhost

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I've been noticing that when WSO2 is sending a request to the Federated Authenticator endpoint the AssertionConsumerServiceURL is being set to https://localhost:9443/commonauth

This seems to be causing issues when testing against testshib. Is there an configuration step I'm missing to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

We can't used AssertionConsumerService(ACS) URL as above **commonauth** URL. If federated to outside ,ACS URL will contain same request URL. Except the set up with dynamic ACS URL.
As a example if you used web app for get SAML Assertion your ACS URL is web app URL. If we used **travelociy.com app** ( [travelocity URL](http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp)) for generate SAML2 Assertion your ACS URL will be [travelocity URL](http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp)